# Laravel api resource with method does't work

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-6, laravel-resource

This is my resource file:

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Wpis extends JsonResource
{

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }

    public function with($request)
    {
        return [
            'qwerty' => 'zaqwsx'
        ];
    }

}
```

It doesn't return my qwerty value. What am I doing wrong, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't included how you return response but make sure you do it like this:

```
return new Wpis(Model::find(1));
```

to get expected result.